# Cloud functions similar/altenative to AWS Lambda Layers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to use [node-qpdf2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qpdf2) which depends on `qpdf` apt package but I could not find it on [System Packages](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/system-packages).

But as you can see on this part of this package docs:

> For example, `qpdf-11.1.0-bin-linux-x86_64.zip` can be directly uploaded as a layer, and has been tested using Amazon Lambda.

So my question is:

Does GCP have a similar function like layers on AWS? If don't, how can I use this `qpdf` zip package on my function?

Comment: GCP has Cloud Run, where you can use docker to build a system image any way you like, and still handle invocations with it with performance and scaling characteristics of Cloud Functions (in fact, modern Cloud Functions is just a convenience wrapper around Cloud Run now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using only `qpdf` standalone package.

There's an Ubuntu Linux running behind Cloud Functions ([see](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment?hl=pt-br)) and `qpdf` zip release is a standalone release with all executables and libaries required built using an Ubunto distro so I can run it using terminal commands in my Cloud Function with [nodejs spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) method.

I only had to extract zip content into a folder where my functions entry point is.

E.g.: In my `package.json`, the `main` prop is pointing to `build/index.js`, so I created a folder inside `build` and put all zip content there:

```
- root_dir
  - build
    - index.js
    - other builded files
    - qpdf_dir
      - zip content
  - src
    - index.ts
    - other ts files
```

Then to start `qpdf` I used node `spawn` method with `cwd` prop pointing to `build/qpdf_dir/bin`:

```
const qpdfPath = path.join( process.cwd(), 'qpdf_dir/bin' )
// as we are running a local file we
// need to add "./" before file name
const process = spawn('./qpdf', [ args ], {
  cwd: qpdfPath
})
```